# $n|a^n-b^n\Rightarrow n|\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}^2$. Show that:
>   $$n|a^n-b^n\Longrightarrow n|\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$$

I’ve tried an induction, but I gave up. Is there a direct proof?

To admin: Please open this post and wait one day before closing it since we are looking for new perspectives.

Comment: I could imagine the converse.

Comment: What if $n=a-b$ ?

Comment: The claim is obviously true for $n=2$.

Comment: Note $n$ acts both as divisor and as exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is prime then it is true. Since $$a^n-b^n ={a^n-b^n\over a-b}\cdot (a-b)$$

$n$ must divide one of them. If it divide the fraction we are done. Suppose it divide $a-b$, then

$${a^n-b^n\over a-b} =a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+...+b^{n-1}\equiv n\cdot a^{n-1} \equiv 0\pmod n$$

and we are done again.

Comment: What about when $n$ isn't a prime?

Comment: Why $n$ must divide one of them?

Comment: By Euclid's lemma (since $n$ is a prime)

Comment: 12|24=3x8 but 12 dont divide 3 or 8

Comment: $12$ isn't prime.

Comment: I misread it. I have not seen that n was prime in the post

Comment: ... but why does $a^{n-1} + .... + b^{n-1} \equiv n a^{n-1} \pmod n$?  Are we assuming $a^{n-1-k}b^{k}\equiv a^{n-1} \pmod n$?  Because $a^n\equiv b^n$ so $a^{n-1-k}b^{k}\equiv a^{k+1}b^{n-k}$?  But... what...

Comment: Because $a\equiv b$

Comment: @Aqua Can you please tell how to approach the case when n is not prime?

Comment: I don't know, I have only a solution when it is prime. You better look at the linked answers. @No-One